# YTD filtering by category - DAX / Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a 'Table' with three columns: Date, Location, Value.

I also have a table 'Tabledates' with a continuous set of dates. Relationships are correctly set.

I have created a measure called YTD with code:

> CALCULATE( SUM( Table[Value] ); DATESYTD( Tabledates[Date] ))

On any graph, the YTD measure is perfect, but if I filter by location, the results of YTD are totally wrong.

Any hint?

[Picture of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEOpP.png)

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'crazy' post and image of the difference, and what it should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the filter on the location is removed when you filter the calendar table.

You can maybe use this function TOTALYTD()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/totalytd-function-dax

It does exactly the same and you can try to filter on the date on your first table not on the date of the calendar table.

something like :

```
TOTALYTD(Sum(Table1[Value]),Table1[Date].[Date])
```

I think that you have bi-directional filtering or something like that between your table and the calendar table and it remove your previous filter on location.